# Good resources for collocations

Tags: discussion, american-english, resources

Can you please point me to a good online resource for verb collocations, for American English? Preferably, something with a lot of examples.

Comment: What kind of verb colocations are you talking about? Phrasal verbs (verbs that go with prepositions after them but those prepositions are not heads of prepositional phrases)?

Comment: OED is pretty good about listing collocations of verbs. I can't claim it is complete, but often enough it has them, moreso than other dictionaries.

Comment: @Mitch Sus2020 is asking for an online resource, which heavily suggests that they are looking for free resources. The OED online is ridiculously expensive.

Comment: http://www.freecollocation.com/ is a free collocation dictionary

Comment: @Mitch 'phrasal verbs' are colligations (grammatically specified) rather than collocations.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh. Mari-Lou's suggested website corroborates that (no phrasal verbs given on search, but many collocated true prepositions). As to 'colligation', it is a new word to me, and cursory web searching seems to support that ['collocation' includes 'colligation'](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-colligation-1689763). It is not clear to me if 'phrasal verb' is a kind of colligation or not, but is certainly a collocation even if the parts are separated by other terms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It seems to go like this [collocation > colligation > phrasal verbs](https://books.google.com/books?id=3_1snsgmqU8C&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=colligation+phrasal+verbs&source=bl&ots=jBQ4pfG7pg&sig=cc1PIL2v3FneCLX9cVn2b_yusio&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT7YTm5NnWAhXhxVQKHa8YCwEQ6AEIPzAC#v=onepage&q=colligation%20phrasal%20verbs&f=false)

Comment: No; collocation and colligation are disjoint features. 'Morning coffee' is a strong collocation whereas 'Morning cocoa' isn't (though it's not ungrammatical). 'The lightning set the woods on fire' uses a colligation whereas 'The rain put the woods off fire' is grammatically unacceptable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this link help at all? I just downloaded it and it's working well.

[Free download Oxford collocations Dictionary](http://www.freecollocation.com)

Answer (score 1):

Some more references:

- [OED online](http://www.oed.com/) At the end of an entry are usually pairs of words starting with the target word.

You get free access to the OED online if you have a public library card number in the US or UK). You may have to access *through* your public library's website rather than directly through OED's sign-on.

- [Google Book NGrams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams) If you search for [road *_NOUN](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=road+*_NOUN&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) you'll get a list (and graph of historic frequencies) of all pairs of words that are 'road' followed by a noun (and you can change the obvious pattern to look for others). Note that this only gives you the highest frequency ones.